# JAXB - how to detect duplicate nodes while unmarshalling

Tags: java, unmarshalling, jaxb2

Is it possible to report duplicate nodes while unmarshalling XML without validating it against XML schema? Suppose XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user xmlns=...>
    <firstName>Peter</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <firstName>Eric</firstName>
</user>
```

and here's the java class (annotations omitted):

```
public class User {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    .... [getters and setters here]
}
```

The above XML gets successfully  unmarshalled into a User object with `firstName=Eric` and `lastName=Smith`. Instead, I want it to fail and report the presence of duplicate element `firstName`.
We don't use validation against XSD because we support both XML and JSON, so chose to use Bean Validation against annotations contained in JAXB beans (generated java classes). Which works pretty well, but obviously cannot take care of the described problem.